# Why node and npm gives blank output but nodejs works on RaspberryPi OS?

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, jupyter-lab, debian-buster

When I was trying to install ipywidgets on JupyterLab, I got the following message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.2) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Fail to get yarn configuration. 
An error occured.
ValueError: Please install nodejs >=10.0.0 before continuing. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.
See the log file for details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-tuyrrcgt.log
```

But I already have those installed via apt. So I took a look in the log:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/sbin/node', 'node-version-check.js']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Looks like node returned nothing. and I tried:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node -v
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm help
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nodejs -v
v10.21.0
```

Looks like `node` or `npm` didn't setup correctly by apt. Am I doing something wrong or the Debian-buster distro is actually "busted".

The package info:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which node
/usr/sbin/node
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache policy node
node:
  Installed: 0.3.2-7.4
  Candidate: 0.3.2-7.4
  Version table:
 *** 0.3.2-7.4 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache policy npm
npm:
  Installed: 5.8.0+ds6-4+deb10u2
  Candidate: 5.8.0+ds6-4+deb10u2
  Version table:
 *** 5.8.0+ds6-4+deb10u2 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I really don't want to `make install` node and npm, making things extra messy.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what do you get when you run `which node` and `which npm`?

Comment: @Teedeez ``/usr/sbin/node`` ``/usr/bin/npm``

Comment: Hmm, not sure what happened, the node's and npm's versions look weird to me, I am very unsure why `node -v` prints nothing for you, maybe try doing `vi /usr/sbin/node` to see if the executable file is somehow empty, if all else fails, you should use Node Version Manager(NVM) to manage your node installation https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm